# Averages using loops and if else statements

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

> hi, I've been asked by my instructor to write a code that can get the >average of 3 grades of a student and output a specific string for
>   each interval of the average (ex. if AVG b/w 70&100
>   cout<<"Excellent\n"; ) but there is a condition in which it is okay
>   for a student to miss one out of three tests. I have been tweaking for
>   hours and I do not know how to create two conditions (two diff. eqns for >averages (one if you miss a test, the other if you don't)
>   also, I don't know how to create the loop, it continues forever , i don't >know why lol. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double test1(0),test2(0),test3(0),AVG,AVG2,counter(1);
    cout << " please write score of  test1\n";
    cin >> test1;

    cout << "Please enter test 2 grade\n";
    cin >> test2;

    cout << "Please enter test 3 grade\n";
    cout << "if test 3 is not there please write in 0\n";
    cin >>test3;

    cout << "test1 score:"<< test1<<"\n";
    cout << "test2 score:"<< test2<<"\n";
    cout << "test3 score:"<< test3<<"\n";

    AVG=(test1+test2+test3)/3;
    AVG2=(test1+test2+test3)/2;

    if (test3==0)
    {
        while (counter<=20)
            cout <<"  Average2  :  "<<AVG2<<"\n";

        if (test3 <=0)
            cout<<"Result (average of two tests):";

        if ((AVG2 <=100) && (AVG2>=70))
            cout<<"Excellent !\n";
        else
            if ((AVG2 <70) && (AVG2>=50))
                cout << "Moderate !\n";
            else
               if ((AVG2 <50) && (AVG2>0))
                   cout << "Fail !\n";
                else
                    if ((AVG2 <0) || (AVG2>100))
                        cout << "Error for avg2!\n";
        counter= counter +1;
    }
    else (!(test3==0));
    {
        while (counter<=20)
        {
            cout<<"Average of three tests:  "<<AVG<<"\n";
            if ((AVG <=100) && (AVG>=70))
                cout<<"Excellent !\n";
            else
                if ((AVG <70) && (AVG>=50))
                    cout << "Moderate !\n";
            else
                if ((AVG <50) && (AVG>0))
                    cout << "Fail !\n";
            else
                if ((AVG <0) || (AVG>100))
                    cout << "Error for avg1!\n";
            counter = counter +1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `else` *what*??

Comment: the `while` loop in the if lasts forever because you need to use parenthesis {}

Comment: what's the meaning of `counter`? Can you clarify what you are doing?

Comment: counter is something i use to stop the loop

Comment: How do I use the parantheses ?

Comment: Was this part of a code obfuscation contest? The indentation and layout are near-unmaintainable. Wait a minute...

Comment: Craig, honestly, chill. It's still code. If you don't want to help okay, fine, way to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here and there you have made some mistakes.But don't worry that's okay.

You have assumed that the student does not take test3 only.But it could be test1 or test2 also.

Another thing to notice is that you have assigned 0 as the score for the test which has not been taken.Again this could create an issue since it could be that the student appeared but scored 0.

I have refined the code and took care of all the corner cases and it does exactly what your instructor wants.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int avg,test1,test2,test3,left=0;
cout<<"Enter the test scores.\n";
cout<<"If a student has not appeared in a test, please enter -1\n";
cout<<"\nTest 1 : ";
cin>>test1;
if(test1==-1)
    left++;

cout<<"\nTest 2 : ";
cin>>test2;
if(test2==-1)
    left++;

cout<<"\nTest 3 : ";
cin>>test3;
if(test3==-1)
    left++;

if(left>1)
{
    cout<<"FAIL : The student has not appeared in more than one tests";
    return 0;
}
else if(left==1)
{
    if(test1==-1)
    {
        avg=(test2+test3)/2;

    }
    else if(test2==-1)
    {
        avg=(test1+test3)/2;
    }
    else if(test3==-1)
    {
        avg=(test1+test2)/2;
    }
}
else if(left==0)
{
    avg=(test1+test2+test3)/3;
}

if(avg>=70 && avg<=100)
{
    cout<<"Excellent !\n";
}
else if(avg>=50 && avg<70)
{
    cout<<"Moderate !\n";
}
else if(avg>=0 && avg<50)
{
    cout<<"Fail !\n";
}
else
{
    cout<<"Internal Computation Error";
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , You don't know how much help you're providing! I only started programming two weeks ago and I haven't fully grasped everything. Thank you again , Joel.

Comment: can you please explain the new code ? Thank you

Comment: Okay Lets see There are two cases either the student takes all the test or leaves one of the tests.But there is one hidden case too,if the student leaves more than two test.Well out of natural intuition I assumed the the student will fail in that case and I created the program in the manner.Alright so lets dive into the program now.I took three variables `test1`,`test2` and `test3` to store the values of the tests.I took another variable `left` to count the number of tests not taken by the student.

Comment: Since a student could have scored 0 in a test taken by the student,we need to indicate a test not taken by some other number. -1 seems to be perfect for this.Now it is not necessary to always take -1 this is just to differentiate this numeral from the score numerals (0-100).When the user enters the marks for a test,it is checked whether the number entered by the user is -1 or not.If it is -1,it indicates that the student has left that particular test.So in this case we update the value of `left` variable to indicate that so far the student has left one test.

Comment: The user then continues entering the test marks for other subjects and checking its value along.Finally,the variables `test1`,`test2`,`test3` will be having the marks of each test and the variable `left` will be having the number of test left by the student.Now we make a check whether `left` is greater than 1 or not.If it is so then we just simply print that the student has failed because of insufficient appearance in exams.But if the value of `left` is less than or equal to one,it means that either the student has taken all the subjects tests(if `left` = 0) or has left one(if `left` = 1)

Comment: Now if the student has taken all the tests,we simply compute the average and store it in a variable called `avg`.But if the student has left one subject,we need to determine which subject was left.You will realize why we took -1 for tests not taken.Now we will check for each test variable : If `test1` is -1, it means the student has taken only `test2` and `test3` so we will compute only the average of those subjects.Similarly we will perform the check for `test2` and `test3`.Now finally we will be having the average of the student's marks.

Comment: Now a simple `if - else-if` construct is necessary to print the appropriate message.Check the value of avg whether it lies in the given range and print its value.Hope this helped you in understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing an infinite loop because in the following statement:

```
while (counter<=20)
    cout <<"  Average2  :  "<<AVG2<<"\n";
```

the loop executes only that line of code forever (i.e. cout). You need to add parenthesis around code you want to execute in each execution:

```
while (counter<=20)
{
    // cout <<"  Average2  :  "<<AVG2<<"\n";
    // all you logic with if-else

    counter = counter +1; // or counter++;
}
```

In this way all the code between `{` and `}` is executed, including the increment of counter.

Comment: thank you so much, your help is highly appreciated

Comment: by the way can you help with the line where i wrote

Comment: else(!(test3==0) the compiler says expression result unused, i don't understand what it means.. thank you again

Comment: by the way now the loop goes 20 times only but I want to change the values for the variable in every loop ,, how can I do that ?

Comment: in this case, you don't need to specify anything after `else` because the condition is exactly the opposite of the one in the `if`.

Comment: okay, thank you :")

Comment: btw there's a break point on a line and i can't remove it.. what can I do about breakpoints>?

Comment: whaat IDE are you using? Visual Studio? In Visual Studio, you can just click on the red dot and you remove the breakpoint. Alternatevely, go to the line with the cursor and press F9

Comment: it's xcode on mac, okay

Comment: btw how can I change the variables everytime the program runs into a new loop ?